# How can I view Arabic/Persian numbers in a HTML page with strict doctype?

Tags: html, numbers, doctype, arabic, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have an HTML page that is right-to-left. When I don't use any doctype, my numbers are in Arabic/Persian, but when I use strict mode they turn to English.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Final//EN">
```

Before adding doctype:

[image: Before adding doctype]

After adding doctype:

[image: After adding doctype]

also I added these meta tags to my page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="fa" />
```

So how can I view Arabic numbers in a page with strict doctype (in IE because Firefox doesn't show Arabic numbers anyway)?

Comment: Which browser? Which doctype? Could you show us an example?

Comment: Which doctype are you using and *is* your data actually UTF-8 encoded? Where are the persian characters coming from, are they in the file? Needs more info.

Comment: the page saved in UTF-8. I simply change "direction" to "rtl" and ie show numbers in persian. an if I change it back to "ltr" numbers will be English.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, a minimal example works for me. You need to provide more information.

Comment: By the way, why is this tagged `xhtml-1.0-strict` when you are using a HTML 4 doctype? Worse, you’re actually using XML self-closing tags in the code. (Not that it makes a difference here.)

Comment: I doubt that a browser who "know" how to convert the numerals like this. Are you sure it's not happening server-side?

Comment: @Konrad I used strict mode because I want to IE works in standard mode not quark mode so I can use css 2.1 features.

Comment: @RoToRa yes I'm sure. because I have a normal grid that show Persian numbers in rtl and Latin numbers in ltr. also I found that this feature only available on IE and before 8 version.

Comment: @mahdi But you are using the *wrong* strict mode, or you tagged your question wrong: the tag says that you are using XHTML but your code says that you are using HTML 4.

Comment: Arabic/Persian numbers are Character, not REAL number/integer.

Answer (score 11):

You can convert English digits to Persian digits using this JavaScript code in your template:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var replaceDigits = function() {
        var map = ["&\#1776;","&\#1777;","&\#1778;","&\#1779;","&\#1780;","&\#1781;","&\#1782;","&\#1783;","&\#1784;","&\#1785;"]
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\d(?=[^<>]*(<|$))/g, function($0) { return map[$0]});
    }
    window.onload = replaceDigits;
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the script. but AFAIK there is no need for the onload attribute for the body tag.

Answer (score 10):

here is a little javascript code that converts a 1234 string to ١٢٣٤ string

```
   var map =
    [
    "&\#1632;","&\#1633;","&\#1634;","&\#1635;","&\#1636;",
    "&\#1637;","&\#1638;","&\#1639;","&\#1640;","&\#1641;"
    ];

    function getArabicNumbers(str)
    {
        var newStr = "";

        str = String(str);

        for(i=0; i<str.length; i++)
        {
            newStr += map[parseInt(str.charAt(i))];
        }

        return newStr;
    }
```

Comment: this worked for me


<script type="text/javascript">
 var map =
    [
     "&\#1632;","&\#1633;","&\#1634;","&\#1635;","&\#1636;",
     "&\#1637;","&\#1638;","&\#1639;","&\#1640;","&\#1641;"
    ];

    function getArabicNumbers(str)
    {
        var newStr = "";

        str = String(str);

        for(i=0; i<str.length; i++)
        {
            newStr += map[parseInt(str.charAt(i))];
        }

        return newStr;
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".arabic-num td").each(function(){
      $(this).html(getArabicNumbers($(this).html()));
     });
    });
</script>

Answer (score 6):

In case you need to replace some English to Arabic numerals and not the whole HTML, pass the number you need to this function.

```js
function toArabicNumeral(en) {
    return ("" + en).replace(/[0-9]/g, function(t) {
        return "٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩".slice(+t, +t+1);
    });
}
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. In this case an eight year old question with nine existing answers should also address what new aspect of the question it is answering. How will this code be used to alter the elements of an ordered list generated with `<ol>`?

Comment: @JasonAller, This code provide a way to replace any English numeral to Arabic numeral which is different than previous replies that replace whole HTML elements. If the case to alter elements of an ordered list generated, css can do the job:
```ol {
    list-style: arabic-indic;
}```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want an XHTML 1.0 Strict document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fa" lang="fa" dir="rtl">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Title here</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Text here</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's an equivalent HTML 4.01 Strict document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Title here</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Text here</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's an equivalent HTML5 page, just for comparison purposes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title here</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Text here</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple to view Arabic/Persian numbers in a HTML page.

I solved the same problem by changing the font name,

In my case I want to display the same character to all users

you can choose a font that contains Arabic-Hndi digits and import it using the css ( @font-face  ) then simply use it,

This works fine for all major browsers (IE .. Firefox .. Chrome)

[look at this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9nmt.png)

here is the full code of the page:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">

@font-face {
    font-family: ArabicTwo_Bold;
    src: url( ArabicTwo_Bold.eot);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: ArabicTwo_Bold;
    src: url( ArabicTwo_Bold.ttf);
}


div , input {
 font-family: ArabicTwo_Bold;
}
</style>


<input type='text' value='هذا نص هندي 123456 ' />
<div> هذا نص هندي 123456  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

firefox default render number to latin
for change this setting go to  addressbar of Firefox and type about:config
this page is advanced setting of firefox
find this line "bidi.numeral" and double click on it
if set value to "1" firefox for render text look at context. if text is persian render number to persian.
if set value to "4" alwase render digit number to persian

Comment: Thank you my friend. Is there something like this for chrome?

Answer (score 2):

try this , hope helps you ;)

between  and

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">


var replaceDigits = function() {
var map =
[
"&\#1632;","&\#1633;","&\#1634;","&\#1635;","&\#1636;",
"&\#1637;","&\#1638;","&\#1639;","&\#1640;","&\#1641;"
]

document.body.innerHTML =
document.body.innerHTML.replace(
/\d(?=[^<>]*(<|$))/g,
function($0) { return map[$0] }
);
}

</script>
```

then in end of body tag insert this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = replaceDigits
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, regardless of the text direction (in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Final//EN">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            body { direction: rtl; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        ۴۲
    </body>
</html>
```

(Omitted the `content-language` since that isn’t necessary here.)

Comment: @mahdi It most certainly does work in Chrome. What’s your browser version? Did you save the file using the correct encoding? I can’t really speak for IE9 (and to be honest I couldn’t care less about MISE) but I don’t really believe that MSIE would convert some Unicode characters into entirely unrelated characters without some prompting. Do you perhaps have a plugin installed that does an automatic Farsi => English translation?

Comment: I use Chrome 10 and yes I saved it with UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

If you use persian fonts like 'BNazanin' and write :

`http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"`
and `http-equiv="Content-Language" content="fa"` in meta tags.

You can then see the numbers in persian.

and if you use `lang='En'` in some tags in your html page the numbers in that tag will be displayed in english.

Comment: the problem is using default fonts like tahoma or arial

Answer (score 1):

```
var map_format_arabic = ["&\#1632;","&\#1633;","&\#1634;","&\#1635;","&\#1636;", "&\#1637;","&\#1638;","&\#1639;","&\#1640;","&\#1641;"];

$.each( $('.format_arabic'), function () {
    var n=$(this).text().replace(/\d(?=[^<>]*(<|$))/g, function($0) { return map_format_arabic[$0]});
    $(this).html(n);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code supports one or multiple digits of an English number which can be converted to Arabic number:

```
function toArabicNumber(enNum) {
    if(isNaN(enNum) || enNum == null){ // Check if not a number or null
        return enNum;
    }

    if(typeof enNum == 'string'){ // if it is a string(number) convert it to number
        enNum = Number(enNum);
    }

    if(enNum < 10){
        return "٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩".substring(enNum, enNum+1);
    }
    else {
        let result = "";
        enNum = enNum + ""; // convert number to string

        for(let i = 0; i < enNum.length; i++){
            let num = Number(enNum[i]); // convert digit by digit to number
            result = result + "٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩".substring(num, num+1);
        }

        return Number(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just specify a persian font like 'B yekan' to them.
all troubleshoots will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
var replaceDigits = function () {
      var map = ["&#1776;", "&#1777;", "&#1778;", "&#1779;", "&#1780;", "&#1781;", "&#1782;", "&#1783;", "&#1784;", "&#1785;"];
      document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\d(?=[^<>]*(<|$))/g, function ($0) {
        return map[$0];
      });
    }
    window.onload = replaceDigits;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toLocalString("fa")` for Persian characters.