# function that works immediately and replaces all the english numbers to arabic numbers

Tags: javascript, unicode, arabic

I have this function

```
var map =
[
"&\#1632;","&\#1633;","&\#1634;","&\#1635;","&\#1636;",
"&\#1637;","&\#1638;","&\#1639;","&\#1640;","&\#1641;"
];

function getArabicNumbers(str)
{
    var newStr = "";

    str = String(str);

    for(i=0; i<str.length; i++)
    {
        newStr += map[parseInt(str.charAt(i))];
    }

    return newStr;
}
```

which is taken from [How can I view Arabic/Persian numbers in a HTML page with strict doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635939/how-can-i-view-arabic-persian-numbers-in-a-html-page-with-strict-doctype)

This function will only work if you put something between the parenthesis in `getArabicNumbers()` when you call out for it.

I want to apply this function on the document from its beginning to its end! how can I do that? Is it possible in javascript? do you recommend it?

any other way to replace English numbers to Arabic numbers using javascript (on the full page not on a string)?

Comment: Why would you want that? Can't you provide the arabic numbers serverside?

Comment: arabic is not supported by the servers.
also, there is some html writings here and there that contains some numbers which I want to convert to Arabic. 
and If I replaced the english number do arabic number manually, then search engines will not recognize them as numbers and will not index them (I have read somebody saying that in here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [walk the DOM tree](http://snipplr.com/view/19815/) and for each textnode call [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with the getArabicNumbers.

I would change the getArabicNumbers function to a regex probably; all you need to do is match 0-9 and then map it using a callback.

**Edit:**
[Here's a little fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zEenn/) I put together for the fun of it and to demonstrate what I'm talking about and it seems to work perfectly although I am a little unsure about the Right-To-Left part...

**Edit2:**
D'oh... You can even do [without the map[] array](http://jsfiddle.net/zEenn/1/).

Comment: The best answer I have seen so far. =)

It works perfectly if you add `style="direction:rtl;"`