# IE and non english numbers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, localization

I am using a font which has non English numbers in it like: `۰, ۱, ۲, ۳, ۴, ۵, ۶, ۷, ۸, ۹,`

I have no problem with Firefox, chrome and opera but the IE....

I have added below css

```
body,input {
   /*The B Roya is the font with persian numbers and is loaded correctly*/
   font-family: 'B Roya', Tahoma, Arial;
   font-size: 18px;
}
```

For  all charters and numbers the fonts is applied correctly. But for inputs the font is applied to characters but not to numbers, The numbers are displayed in English!!

I have found that applying the `direction:rtl` to input will force IE to show numbers in Persain !! But the numbers will be put in the left!

To correct this I have added `text-align:left` now the number is displayed correctly in correct position but when you put cursor in the input box, and hit the left arrow the caret moves to the right and vise versa.

See the complete story at: http://jsfiddle.net/w6mnN/5/

Any comments !!

Comment: Maybe try to use content editable paragraphs to deal with this font http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

Comment: @singe31 The problem is with input tag !!

Comment: @Alireza Fattahi - did you tried possible solution from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635939/how-can-i-view-arabic-persian-numbers-in-a-html-page-with-strict-doctype) ?

Comment: @PaulTomkiel unfortunately it seems a bug in IE :(

Comment: @Alireza Fattahi - so probably you should answer your own question with this information :)

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately it seems a bug in IE and I could not find any way to fix it.

Interestingly you see this behavior on office tools too