# CSS first-line bug with mix Arabic and numbers

Tags: html, css

When I insert numbers in a arabic text with styled first-line combined with font-size, the rendering seem to switch to ltr.
Can any one help me to find a solution for this bug? It switch to normal when I delete the number from the text or delete font-size.

```html
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">

<head>
  <style>
    li::first-line {
      font-size: 130%;
      color: RGB(68, 114, 196);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li>
      هو آلة إلكترونية لها قابلية استقبال البيانات ومعالجتها إلى 10 معلومات ذات قيمة. كما يخزنها في وسائط تخزين مختلفة، وفي الغالب يكون قادراً على تبادل هذه النَتَائِج والمعلومات مع أجهزة أخرى متوافقة ومتطورة. تستطيع أسرع الحواسيب اليوم القيام بمئات مليارات
      العمليات الحسابية والمنطقية في ثوانٍ قليلة.
    </li>

    <li>
      هو آلة إلكترونية لها قابلية استقبال البيانات ومعالجتها إلى معلومات ذات قيمة. كما يخزنها في وسائط تخزين مختلفة، وفي الغالب يكون قادراً على تبادل هذه النَتَائِج والمعلومات مع أجهزة أخرى متوافقة ومتطورة. تستطيع أسرع الحواسيب اليوم القيام بمئات مليارات العمليات
      الحسابية والمنطقية في ثوانٍ قليلة.
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I view Arabic/Persian numbers in a HTML page with strict doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635939/how-can-i-view-arabic-persian-numbers-in-a-html-page-with-strict-doctype)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I dont want to switch to persian numbers, and the web page is ambeded in a flutter webview with javascript disabled for optimality.